# How can I stop GIMP from adding background color to my text when I convert file types?

Tags: gimp, file-format, image-format

When I add a text to my image in GIMP, it shows up with a transparent background (which I want). However when I convert the default GIMP file from xcf to a jpg, the text suddenly has a white background, which I don't want. Is there a way to stop this from happening? Images attached.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE.  I'm not sure what is going on in your screen shot.  What image Mode is the original image in?  Make sure it is in RGB. Do  *Image > Mode > RGB* before you start editing. This is just a guess though.  It would be easier perhaps to answer this if you show your whole screen, with the layers panel showing so we can see how you constructed this.  Also note that the JPEG format doesn't support transparency (which has nothing to do with GIMP, it's a limitation of the file format itself).